# How to set swt tabitem inactive?

Tags: java, tabs, swt

I'm designing a gui based on `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem`.

Is there a way to show a `TabItem` inside a `TabFolder` as "inactive", i.e. with the usual light gray color and having all the contained elements not active as well?

It is something in other systems I can design. I thought it would be possible with swt as well, but I'm new to this environment and after Googling on this topic, I couldn't find any solution. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to set `TabItem` inactive (disabled), because there will be no way how to click on the selected `TabItem` then. But is pretty easy to disable content of selected `TabItem`. Just get `Control` which is binded to the `TabItem` instance and call `setEnable(false)`.

```
/*
 * TabFolder example snippet: create a tab folder (six pages)
 *
 * For a list of all SWT example snippets see
 * http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/
 */
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class TabItemDisable {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    final Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder (shell, SWT.BORDER);
    Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea ();
    tabFolder.setLocation (clientArea.x, clientArea.y);
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        TabItem item = new TabItem (tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText ("TabItem " + i);
        Button button = new Button (tabFolder, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText ("Page " + i);
        item.setControl (button);
    }
    tabFolder.pack ();

    // disabling content of selected TabItems
    tabFolder.getTabList()[0].setEnabled(false);
    tabFolder.getTabList()[2].setEnabled(false);
    tabFolder.getTabList()[4].setEnabled(false);

    shell.pack ();
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Sorceror was pretty cool. But i have a little note that the code

getTabList() in

```
tabFolder.getTabList()[0].setEnabled(false);
tabFolder.getTabList()[2].setEnabled(false);
tabFolder.getTabList()[4].setEnabled(false);
```

means the "tab order list" not the "tab item" itself. So if you want to set some  Enabled  some disable (  tabFolder.getTabList()[0].setEnabled(true); ) the order maybe not correct.